# Keep getting AmbiguousMatchExceptions with aspnet-api-versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, aspnet-api-versioning

I'm sure it's just me, but after using multiple sources, approaches, and many takes, I just can't seem to get even the simplest example of `aspnet-api-versioning` to work. I keep getting AmbiguousMatchExceptions for different versions of an endpoint. What am I doing wrong? What should I change in order to make it work?

```
using Asp.Versioning;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        builder.Services
            .AddApiVersioning()
            .AddMvc();

        var app = builder.Build();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
}

[ApiVersion("1.0"), Route("v{version:apiVersion}/hello")]
public class HelloV1Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() => "v1";
}

[ApiVersion("2.0"), Route("v{version:apiVersion}/hello")]
public class HelloV2Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Get() => "v2";
}
```

Comment: I would say it's the 'AddEndpointsApiExplorer()' causing the issues, because by default it isn't looking at the version attributes. That's a starting point - remove that line, and if it works, you've narrowed it down to `ApiVersionAttribute` + `EndpointsApiExplorer`

Comment: Hi @AndrewWilliamson thanks for your reply. I removed the line, but no luck. I still get the `AmbiguousMatchException`. Updated my example without that line

Comment: You've got some conflicting tags - this looks like an Asp.Net Core application, not asp.net-web-api2. Also note the ASP.NET API Versioning package has multiple variants (Asp.Net Core, Asp.Net Core MVC), and I suspect if you use the wrong one it will compile but not actually look at the attribute. Can you list the package references you are using?

Comment: I'm using `Asp.Versioning.Mvc` (v6.1.0). Got there after reading through the move from Microsoft, but I can't seem to find a more appropriate package. Fixed the tags, thanks!

Comment: Choose any of them https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/main/examples

Comment: Had some trouble getting those to run, but finally managed. However: it works within the (stripped down) solution, but they won't work for me when I use the nuget package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the setup is incomplete. It should be:

```cs
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning().AddMvc();
```

The names are intentionally similar, but contrary to some people's belief, this doesn't add the full MVC stack. API Versioning `6.0` adds a new `IApiVersioningBuilder` so that all related extensions can be grouped together. *Minimal APIs* are supported in `6.0`, which means there is no longer any dependency on any part of MVC Core. This is what `AddApiVersioning()` now does.  To add in MVC Core to support controllers the way that it worked in previous versions, you have to call `AddMvc()`. This gives you the most flexiblity in choosing how you want to version your APIs. You can even mix and match *Minimal APIs* and controllers.

For quick reference, here is the gambit of configuration options:

```cs
services.AddApiVersioning()     // Core API Versioning services with support for Minimal APIs
        .AddMvc()               // API version-aware extensions for MVC Core
        .AddApiExplorer()       // API version-aware API Explorer extensions
        .AddOData()             // API versioning extensions for OData
        .AddODataApiExplorer(); // API version-aware API Explorer extensions for OData
```

> Obviously, if you're not using the API Explorer or OData packages, those extensions do not apply.

In addition, each controller must be decorated with `[ApiController]` so that API Versioning can disambiguate between an API controller and a UI controller, which otherwise have the same base type. You can also use `[assembly: ApiController]` to make all controllers in the project an API controller.

`AddEndpointsApiExplorer()` is completely unrelated. If you're not using *Minimal APIs*, then it's unnecessary. If you're adding OpenAPI to document your APIs, then you'll want to add the API Explorer extensions.

There are a lot of notes in the [discussions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/discussions) and release notes, but the documentation isn't up-to-date. There is an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/885) tracking that and updates are coming. The best place to start for reference is to look at the [latest examples](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/main/examples/AspNetCore/WebApi).

Comment: I added `AddMvc` but I still get the same result. Also, the compiler tells me there's no definition of `AddApiExplorer` in `IApiVersioningBuilder`  so I get the feeling that I'm using the wrong package (Asp.Versioning.Mvc v6.1.0) could that be it? I tried the examples, but they too won't build (removed everything form the solution but the examples, referenced the nuget package, I get multiple missing definition errors, so something is off but I can't figure out what it is) (changed the example accordingly)

Comment: Update: tried the examples without referencing the nuget package (stripped all the aspnet framework stuff out because it needs 4.5 SDK's that seem no longer available) and now I get results. So could it be that the latest nuget package is not the same as the code in the git repository?

Comment: You _almost_ had me stumped. The issue is that when you use controllers, there isn't necessarily a clean way to disambiguate UI controllers from API controllers. This was addressed by the `ApiControllerAttribute` in ASP.NET Core 2.1. API Versioning has a `IApiControllerFilter` and `IApiControllerSpecification` service which determines if a controller should be included. There is a built-in filter for `[ApiController]`. To fix the issue, apply `[ApiController]` to each controller or `[assembly: ApiController]` to apply to all controllers in the project/assembly.

Comment: And this then worked! Of all the combinations I tried, I apparently did not use both `AddMvc()` and `ApiControllerAttribute` at the same time. Their names seem to contradict  eachother somewhat, so that might be the reason. Could you add the attribute to your answer? Then I can flag it as accepted. (Also, I'm still kind of interested why I get the missing definitions, and broken examples with the actual nuget package. Care to shed some light on that?)

Comment: Done. Unsure why you'd be having an issue with the examples. They use project references instead of package references, but that's purely so I'm not updating the version numbers all the time. It also helps avoid build-breaks against the latest versions. The CI process includes the examples so there is no reason it shouldn't all build. I use the examples a lot for repros. Occasionally, I swap out the project for a package reference to make sure I'm seeing the same thing and I haven't run into a problem yet. Feel free to open an issue in the repo and we can dive into with more detail.